# pythonのsortについて

Tags: python, アルゴリズム, lambda, sort

あるlistの中の0を全部最後に移動する問題がありました。
たとえば[0,1,0,3,4,5]->[1,3,4,5,0,0]

回答を見たところ、一行で可能でした
(numsをinputのlistとすると)

```
nums.sort(cmp=lambda a,b:-1 if b==0 else 0)
```

しかしこのコードの括弧の中がよく理解できません。
どなたか解説していただけないでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cmpに指定されているlambda関数は二つのことをやっています。

1. もし比較先の値が0の時は、比較元の値が何であっても0の方が値が大きいとする(cmpの値が-1)
2. 0でない時は両者を同値とする(cmpの値が0)

こうすればリストの中の0は他の値よりも大きな値の扱いになるので、すべて右側に移動することになります。0以外の値はソートされずその場所に留まることになります。下の例なら1,4,3,5はソートされずに元の順序を維持していることがわかります。

```
>>> nums=[0,1,0,4,3,5]
>>> nums.sort(cmp=lambda a,b:-1 if b==0 else 0)
>>> print nums
[1, 4, 3, 5, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

lambda を分解してみました。
sort に渡す cmp パラメータには、2つの引数を取って、返り値で大小を表現する関数を渡します。
http://docs.python.jp/2/howto/sorting.html#cmp

```
def my_cmp(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

nums = [0,1,0,3,4,5]
nums.sort(cmp=my_cmp)
assert nums == [1, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0]
```